# what is filekey attribute and how can set filekey attribute of any document in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, version-control, dms, file-attributes

plz any buddy share demo program about file version control of any document and how can uniquely identify that document at the time of when we uploading.

http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file.attribute/BasicFileAttributes/Java_BasicFileAttributes_fileKey_.htm#Example

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  
  {
    BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/tutorial/Java/JavaFX", "Topic.txt");
    attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println(attr.fileKey());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing some concepts here: you are talking file version control but filesystem attributes.

A [`FileAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileAttribute.html) is what its name says: an attribute for a file. What attributes are defined depend on the [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) implementation. `Paths.get()` will return a `Path` from the default `FileSystem`.

For instance, files on a Unix system will have attributes to tell whether the file can be read/written/executed by user/group/other. Files on a DOS filesystem will have attributes such as hidden.

But those are *dependent on the filesystem*. If you copy a file from one system to another, you will lose these attributes.

One can imagine however to write a `FileSystem` implementation for CVS for instance, where each file has a version; then you could define a `CVSFileAttribute` with a version, yes.

Comment: thanx..so how can atually implement version control and how can uniquely identify any document. beacause i was search about filekey(). it is uniquely identfy any file.. but i dont know how is possible..so plz help me..

Comment: Just use an existing version control system such as git

Comment: i dont know git..some explanation or any futher link about it..plz share me..or any demo program if u have??